# Weird preview on custom camera implementation

Tags: android, android-camera, photo

I've implemented a custom camera activity in my app. The camera works pretty well on my nexus 5. However on an Alcatel One Touch Star, when I stop the preview to show the snapshot, I get this preview

[image]

Furthermore, the byte array of the `PictureCallback` is correct. Infact, if I decode the array into a `Bitmap`, I can see it correctly.

Here is my implementation of the `SurfaceView` as camera preview.

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;
private int mPhotoRotation;

public CameraPreview(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;

    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    List<String> focusModes = parameters.getSupportedFocusModes();

    if (focusModes != null && focusModes.contains(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE))
        parameters.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
    else if (focusModes != null && focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO))
        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
    if (parameters.getSupportedFlashModes() != null && parameters.getSupportedFlashModes().contains(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO))
        parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);

    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Camera.Size size = getOptimalPreviewSize(previewSizes, width, height);

        parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

        Display display = ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        mPhotoRotation = 0;
        if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0) {
            mPhotoRotation = 90;
        } else if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
            mPhotoRotation = 180;
        }
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(mPhotoRotation);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }
}

private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetRatio = (double) h / w;

    Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    int targetHeight = h;

    for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
            continue;
        if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
        }
    }

    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
    }
    return optimalSize;
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
}

public int getPhotoRotation() {
    return mPhotoRotation;
}

}
```

When the user take the photo, this code is executed

```
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallback);
```

and the callback just keep a backup of the byte array and stop the preview.

```
mPictureCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            mPhotoJpeg = data;
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }
    };
```

So what is the cause of this behaviour? Why only on an alcatel and not on the nexus 5?

Comment: This looks like the resolution is wrong somehow... Like you're reading every 641 pixels instead of 640...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959298/android-camera-preview-doesnt-look-nice/14959394#14959394 may help

Comment: @Rajesh no.. Still same problem :(

Comment: Use that class it self it should work, cus I used it and I have a running app

Comment: The problem is that also my version works on a nexus 5... but on an alcatel one touch start it doesn't.